Почему PyСharm не выдает подсказки?
В PyCharm, в проекте без виртуальной среды - впрочем, в проекте с виртуальной средой то же самое, - где-то день назад при написании функции product в скобках, после указания массива при написании букв re, сразу выводилась подсказка - repeat. Сейчас оного не происходит.
Ни так:
import itertools
for a in itertools.product((0,1),rep)

ни так:
from itertools import product
for a in product((0,1),rep)

как выглядят мои подсказки

Помогите, пожалуйста, буду признателен
